# Kestrel goes to 100% cpu under high load and stays that way even if load is decreasing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am facing a very difficult situation. I migrated a production web site from asp.net 4.5 to asp.net core 1.1. The site in asp.net 4.5 was hosted on IIS 8.5, 3 servers 4 cores / 7Gb RAM, and a traffic of 2 millions users a day. Everything was working fine.

Now, when I run the web site with core, hosted with Debian 8, nginx as a reverse proxy and Kestrel, I often see that the service goes to 100% in many situations.
As there are many controllers on the site, it is difficult to narrow down to one issue. But I think I've managed to reproduce one situation in particular.

The scenario is a generation of multiple images based on parameters sent to an async controller of the site. These parameters let me generate a html, this html is sent to another external service, and this service generates the image with phantomjs.
Most of the time, the image generated has to be split in multiple parts, so that they can be integrated in an html page to be clickable.

So for example, we have a web page having this kind of html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><img src="http://www.my-web-site.com/images/GetImages?index=0&...."></td>
    <td><img src="http://www.my-web-site.com/images/GetImages?index=1&...."></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here are the steps:
- Call to async GetImage

If index = 0
- Html is generated
- Send HTML to HtmlToImageServer with async HttpClient (only one static instance)
- Wait for the image index 0 to be ready by checking a database every 500 ms with `await Task.Delay(500)` (can take up to 2 or 3 seconds)
- Redirects to image url when ready

If index > 0
- Wait for the image index n to be ready with `await Task.Delay(500)`
- Redirects to image url when ready

The scenario works, that's for sure. But as I was saying, from time to time, the cpu goes to 100% and no request is served anymore. The server become unresponsive, and all I can do is kill the process.
The exact same scenario works with asp.net 4.5 with IIS.

I think my servers are tuned properly, nginx is configured properly (I tried with nginx on a separate server). I also tried with more powerful servers -> 8 core / 14Gb ram, the exact same happens.

I hope my scenario is clear. I don't know if this is a bug from Kestrel. The only thing I can think of is that there is an issue with my use of async / await, and there would be a deadlock somewhere, but to my mind, this wouldn't work at all if this was the case ?
I tried to run the service under Windows to be able to profile it. I solved a lot of issues with that I think. But it's still not working.
What should I be looking for ?

Let me know if I can clarify any point, and many many thanks for your help. I have been working on this issue for a month now, and I am out of ideas.

EDIT : 
I finally found some solution / workaround.

First, I made a mistake by setting the minimum threads of the ThreadPool with a value that is too high (32675). This value was found by getting it from the Windows .net 4.5 site.
When I set this value to min 200 / max 200 / completion 200, it seems that the site handles requests in a better way.

But the other thing is that I configured Nginx to handle 80000 requests per core. The problem here seems to be that if nginx sends too many requests, kestrel keeps accepting new requests and it is overwhelmed because it is waiting for http clients requests to answer,

So now, I configured Nginx to handle 512 requests with only 1 core. It seems to be ok, but when there is a spike, nginx complains about not having enough worker connections. If I try to set 1024 instead of 512, the cpu goes very fast to 100%.

The strange thing is that it didn't happen with iis + asp.net 4.5. Is there anything I'm missing here ?

Comment: A bug in kestrel is unlikely but not impossible. Profiling should be possible on Linux using LTTng, but this is still a widely undocumented area. Alternatively, you can just attach a remote debugger, break the execution, and display the call stacks ("parallel stacks" tab in Visual Studio). It could help you pinpointing the issue. If you can't get the remote debugger to work, you can also work with a memory dump

Comment: Remote debugger could work yes, but I'm afraid the overhead will really important... As I said, 2 million people per day. I'll try it anyway. I did some profiling with dotTrace, but same here, the overhead on the server prevents from seeing the real issue I think. Could you think of performance counters I should look for ? Thanks!

Comment: I was not thinking about letting the remote debugger attached at all time. Rather, when you see the CPU capping at 100%, remove the traffic from the server then attach the remote debugger to understand what is still running

Comment: I've tried to attached the remote debugger on my process. It shows the same thing as the profiler did, my queries to Mongo get stuck, waiting to acquire the connections (that's the database I'm talking about) whereas mongodb is fully available...

Comment: There isn't much more I can do. You may be leaking connections or something like that, but it's not really something you can debug through stackoverflow :p

Comment: You can see EDIT if you have other ideas... Thanks !

Comment: Tweaking the threadpool is more often than not a bad idea. You should leave the default value unless you're absolutely sure of what you're doing. You also seem to have issues related to request queuing (which most certainly works differently between ASP.NET 4.5 and Kestrel), but I'm not sure how to tweak it. I'm fairly certain it's tweakable though

Comment: Actually, I would like to be sure of what I am doing, but I'm not :) The thing I'm sure of is that leaving default values creates a deadlock when my site starts. It can't create all my connection pools for my differents databases...
Default value is 4, it is certainly not enough when there is a high load on the site :(

Comment: Starting with .NET 4, the threadpool is able to automatically manage its own size. It grows slowly (about two threads per second) so sometimes you may want to tweak the minimum size to speed up application startup, but overall it does a very good job